# Find the value of $a^2-b^2+c^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be real numbers such that $a − 7b + 8c = 4$ and $8a + 4b − c = 7$. What is the
value of $a^2-b^2+c^2$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given $a + 8c= 7b + 4$ and $8a - c = -4b + 7$

Now Squaring both equation, We get

\begin{align}a^2 + 64c^2 + 16ac&=49b^2 + 16 + 56b\tag{1} \\
64a^2 + c^2 - 16ac&=16b^2 + 49 - 56b\tag{2}\end{align}

Summing these two equations gives

$$ 65a^2 + 65c^2 = 65b^2 + 65 \Rightarrow  a^2 - b^2 + c^2 = 1 $$

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it solving the two equations for $b$ and $c$ to be expressed as functions of $a$. This would give $$b=\frac{12}{5}-\frac{13 a}{5}\qquad c=\frac{13}{5}-\frac{12 a}{5}$$ Now, replace in the expression, expand and simplify.